# Python: How to remove empty quotes and a new line from the beginning of the string?

Tags: python, parsing

Below is the string I'm operating on.

```
'exampleURL': ' '
                               'https://someurl.com'
```

I'm trying to clean it up using the code below. But for some reason, it doesn't work.

```
value_to_keep = (value_to_keep.rstrip('"').lstrip('"').rstrip("\n").lstrip("\n").rstrip("'").lstrip("'"))
```

I want the desired output to be

```
'exampleURL': 'https://someurl.com'
```

What is it that I'm missing here?

Comment: Have you tried going one action at a time instead of the entire chain? This way you can spot undesired result(s).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question. I have solved the issue by improving the pattern.

```
rstrip("' '").lstrip("' '")
```

Instead of one single quote, I have added two with a space. Because, that's how it is in the string.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the replace method and replace(" ", "")

```
    foo = {
           'exampleURL': '                           
       https://someurl.com'.replace(" ", "")
    }

print(foo['exampleURL'])

Output: https://someurl.com
```